# Java FX Scene Builder on Idea wrong Scene builder exe

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

When Idea asked to choose Scene Builder executable file, I occasionally chose wrong file and not Scene builder cannot launch. I have searched hard to change this configuration in Idea but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change it here:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Settings]